# Subclassing QMessageBox Static API

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I created a subclass of `QMessageBox` called `CustomQMessageBox` and I want certain actions to take place in the constructor of the subclass. Here is my class:

Header:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMQMESSAGEBOX_H
#define CUSTOMQMESSAGEBOX_H
#include <QMessageBox>

class CustomQMessageBox : public QMessageBox
{
public:
    CustomQMessageBox();
};

#endif // CUSTOMQMESSAGEBOX_H
```

Cpp:

```
#include "customqmessagebox.h"

CustomQMessageBox::CustomQMessageBox()
{
    qDebug() << "yo";
}
```

When I create an instance of `CustomQMessageBox` the constructor is called and `qDebug` says `yo`. However, if I call the static API methods the constructor isn't called.

```
//constructor is called
CustomQMessageBox cbox;

//constructor is not called
CustomQMessageBox::question(this, "Title", "Question?", QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

Why isn't the constructor being called when I use the static methods of `QMessageBox`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Static methods don't instantiate the class object they're associated with. Unless you've made a singleton or something.

Comment: @vincent So I can't use the static methods for my subclass at all?

Comment: You can, but you just won't be able to access variables associated with an instantiated class unless they are also static. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @vincent Ah. I ask because I already have dozens of static `QMessageBox` calls all over my program. I wanted an easy way to stylize all of them the same way and figured subclassing would be the way to go... guess not...

Comment: Subclassing is the way to go. I know your pain and will show you an example.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a class I frequently use which is derived from QMessageBox. You can use the constructor to initiate custom buttons. And you could derive from this class if you needed something more concrete.

If you wanted to get a button role, you could call messageBox->buttonRole(QAbstractButton* buttonInQuestion);

header.

```
#ifndef MESSAGEBOX_H
#define MESSAGEBOX_H

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>

class MessageBox : public QMessageBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MessageBox(QWidget* parent, const QString& title, const QString& text,
               QMessageBox::Icon icon = QMessageBox::NoIcon,
               const QString& btnText1 = "", QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole1 = QMessageBox::AcceptRole,
               const QString& btnText2 = "", QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole2 = QMessageBox::InvalidRole,
               const QString& btnText3 = "", QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole3 = QMessageBox::InvalidRole);
    virtual ~MessageBox();

    virtual QPushButton* addButton(const QString& btnText, QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole);
    QPushButton* button(const unsigned int& index) const;
    bool clicked_button(const unsigned int& index) const;

private:
    QPushButton *_button1;
    QPushButton *_button2;
    QPushButton *_button3;
};

#endif // MESSAGEBOX_H
```

class

```
#include "messagebox.h"

MessageBox::MessageBox(QWidget* parent, const QString& title, const QString& text,
                       QMessageBox::Icon icon,
                       const QString& btnText1, QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole1,
                       const QString& btnText2, QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole2,
                       const QString& btnText3, QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole3)
    : QMessageBox(icon, title, text,QMessageBox::NoButton, parent),
      _button1(0), _button2(0), _button3(0)
{
    _button1 = addButton(btnText1, btnRole1);
    _button2 = addButton(btnText2, btnRole2);
    _button3 = addButton(btnText3, btnRole3);
}

MessageBox::~MessageBox() {

}

QPushButton* MessageBox::addButton(const QString& btnText, QMessageBox::ButtonRole btnRole) {
    if (btnRole != QMessageBox::InvalidRole) {
        if (btnText.compare("") != 0) {
            return QMessageBox::addButton(btnText, btnRole);
        } else {
            QString stdText("?");
            switch (btnRole) {
            case QMessageBox::AcceptRole: stdText = tr("&OK"); break;
            case QMessageBox::RejectRole: stdText = tr("&Cancel"); break;
            case QMessageBox::YesRole: stdText = tr("&Yes"); break;
            case QMessageBox::NoRole: stdText = tr("&No"); break;
            default: break;
            }
            return QMessageBox::addButton(stdText, btnRole);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

QPushButton* MessageBox::button(const unsigned int& index) const {
    switch(index) {
    case 0: return _button1;
    case 1: return _button2;
    case 2: return _button3;
    default: return 0;
    }
}

bool MessageBox::clicked_button(const unsigned int& index) const {
    return this->clickedButton() == button(index);
}
```

example usage...

```
    MessageBox msg(0, tr("Add Icon"), tr("Icon list already contains this icon!"), QMessageBox::Warning);
    msg.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like your approach, however I'm not yet sure if this is the way I'll go. This doesn't return the `QMessageBox::StandardButton` that was selected does it?

Comment: You could if you called msg->standardButton(QAbstractButton* btn). You can retrieve specific buttons from the class for this reason.

Comment: I suppose my greater point was that this approach doesn't really make things much easier if I still have to go through and edit every static call, name the buttons, call exec, call msg->standardButton, etc. At that point, I would be better off just instantiating the class and using the property API. I appreciate the simplicity of the static call, I just wanna change the colors and stuff :P

Comment: Fair enough. You could always write some functions to do more.